# External Monitor Not Working with Ubuntu 18.04 (Razer Blade 2017)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, display, hdmi

A month ago, I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, and I noticed that my external monitor does not display anything when connected to my laptop via HDMI cable. I know nothing physically is wrong because windows 10 can detect and use the external monitor on my laptop.

In 16.04 the external display worked when I switched to my NVIDA graphics card. I use nvidia-driver-415 for my NVIDIA GTX 1060 graphics card. However, the NVIDIA X Server Settings Window is missing many settings. I can only change prime profiles which, I believe, actually works.

What NVIDIA X Server Settings Window should [look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QftM.png)

What my NVIDIA X Server Settings Window [looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQScJ.png)

Also, when I run xrandr, it does not even know I have an HDMI port:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 
8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted 
right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this?